# Command to get to the Container Prompt After Entrypoint

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-entrypoint

What command can be added at the bottom of the Dockerfile to get to container prompt after the ENNTRYPOINT? The Dockerfile runs okay. Just that it goes back to the prompt from where it was executed.

```
 # Pull base image
From ubuntu:18.04
LABEL maintainer="tester@gmail.com"

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential python3.6 python3.6-dev python3-pip python3.6-venv
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN python3.6 -m pip install pip --upgrade
RUN pip3 install pytest pytest-cache
RUN pip3 install pylint
RUN pip3 install requests

# Create working directory
RUN mkdir /testsuite

# Copy project
COPY comments_categories_api  /testsuite/comments_categories_api
COPY comments_posts_api  /testsuite/comments_posts_api/
RUN chmod -R a+rwX testsuite/
# Set working directory

WORKDIR /testsuite
# Set Python version
RUN echo alias python='/usr/bin/python3' >> ~/.bashrc
# RUN echo cd testsuite/ >> ~/.bashrc

# Define ENTRYPOINT
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /testsuite/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/testsuite/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/testsuite/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Can you post the docker run command that you use to run your container?

Comment: docker run -it vip_app:v0.1 /bin/bash

Answer (score 2):

End your docker-entrypoint.sh with "$@". This is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Hello

$@
```

=== UPDATE

Based on your comment, the file should be:

```
#!/bin/bash

pytest -v

$@
```

Comment: I have pytest -v inside the .sh file. Are you saying add $@ on the second line?

Comment: Got this error. `
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: argument -v/--verbose: ignored explicit argument '\r'` : not founddocker-entrypoint.sh: 3: /testsuite/docker-entrypoint.sh:

Comment: You are on windows... :((( Your file has Windows end-line characters. You should save it in Linux format and then it will work. Or install "dos2unix" inside the container and run "dos2unix /testsuite/docker-entrypoint.sh" as part of your build, just before the ENTRYPOINT

Comment: Step 17/20 : RUN "dos2unix /testsuite/docker-entrypoint.sh"
 ---> Running in 05c22feb885a
/bin/sh: 1: dos2unix /testsuite/docker-entrypoint.sh: not found

Comment: You forgot to install the utility (I mentioned install and run). Add "RUN apt-get install -y dos2unix" with the other commands that install the rest of the packages.

Comment: #install dos2unix
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install dos2unix && \
    apt-get clean . I have this in the file.

Comment: For some reason dos2unix cannot find the .sh file. it is in the same directory as the Dockerfile. [Error message: Step 17/20 : RUN dos2unix ./docker-entrypoint.sh
 ---> Running in 29ccb742c463
dos2unix: ./docker-entrypoint.sh: No such file or directory
dos2unix: Skipping ./docker-entrypoint.sh, not a regular file.]

Comment: Can you update the post with your latest version of your Dockerfile?

Comment: Worked. I mis-understood. THis did it. COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /testsuite/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN dos2unix /testsuite/docker-entrypoint.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192805/discussion-between-rssregex-and-mihai).

Comment: @RSSregex can you mark this as accepted answer? otherwise it looks like an open discussion still

Answer (score 1):

After the ENTRYPOINT, definitionally, the container exits.

It sounds like what you're saying is that you want a container that first runs some test, then launches an interactive shell.  You need to make a shell script that does that

```
#!/bin/sh
pytest -v
sh
```

and then make that script be the main process of the image.

---

I have two style comments here, which reading other comments also might matter to you.  You mention trying to run an interactive shell with

```
docker run -it vip_app:v0.1 /bin/bash
```

If you declare the process command with CMD, your `/bin/bash` command replaces CMD and you will get an interactive shell.  If you declare it with ENTRYPOINT, `/bin/bash` is passed as an argument to the ENTRYPOINT (and probably gets totally ignored).  I tend to prefer CMD to ENTRYPOINT if I don't clearly need both.

You also try to change the default `python` command using a `.bashrc` file.  `.bashrc` doesn't get read in many common cases.  For example, if you

```
docker run --rm vip_app:v0.1 python myapp.py
```

the `.bashrc` will not get read and you will run `/usr/bin/python` (which is probably Python 2.7).  I just wouldn't install "convenience" things like this in an image at all.

Comment: I have this my python files. #!/usr/bin/python3. Could I remove this from the Dockerfile - RUN echo alias python='/usr/bin/python3' >> ~/.bashrc. ?

Comment: Since you mentioned CMD, How can I replace ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile? At the end of the Dockerfile, I want pytest to run in  the folder specified, and be at the container prompt.

Comment: Literally just replace ENTRYPOINT with CMD.  They're the same syntax.